# Loop through an array of dictionaries at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, tableview

I  have an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has one category. I want to fill a tableview with all of the dictionaries with one category in common, which was selected in a previous tableview.

```
NSDictionary *name = [sortedNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableString *currentCat = [name objectForKey:@"category"];

if ([currentCat isEqualToString:catSelected]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [name objectForKey:@"title"];
}
```

As you could've guessed, if the first two dictionaries in the array **are not** of the category selected type, but the third one is, then the **third** cellrow gets filled in.

How do I approach this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a mutable array in .h file  In viewWillAppear init and add objects for that array using your code like

```
  array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0;i<[sortedNames count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *name = [sortedNames objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableString *currentCat = [name objectForKey:@"category"];

    if ([currentCat isEqualToString:catSelected]) {
        [array addObject:[name objectForKey:@"title"]];
    }
}
```

In  numberOfRowsInSection method give

```
[array count];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
cell.textLabel.text =[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct an `NSMutableArray` on loading your view controller. This array would only contain the objects you want to display in that table view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.namesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in sortedNames) {
        if ([(NSString *)[dict objectForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:catSelected]) {
            [newArray addObject:dict];
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you assign based on the index:

```
if (indexPath.row < [namesArray count]) {    // Just incase...
    cell.textLabel.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The key idea here is that we don't bring data we don't need for the table view.

Comment: Where exactly did you get [name objectForKey:@"category"] from? I looped through the dictionaries with NSDictionary *name = [sortedNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but there isnt an indexPath in viewdidload.

Comment: @MaikelS: Oops, sorry - little typo. That should read `[dict objectForKey:@"category"]`. I've edited my answer.